# linux system c quoting

Tags: c, linux, redirect, system, call

On an embedded system with Linux as OS I want to call a 3rd party binary to retrieve data from a database and to append this data to an existing file.
The command string which is handed over to the system() function looks like:

```
"export_from_db >> /tmp/myFile"
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. `/tmp/myFile` never gets created! If I omit the redirection, then the database export is printed to stdout.

I wonder if system() and the redirection via ">>" go together well?  On the prompt I successfully tested this command `"export_fom_db >> /tmp/myFile"`! Does anybody know how to achieve it using system()? Is there some kind of quoting necessary?

Answer (score 1):

hm.. Actually, it seems ok for me.. this is exactly what system() is for - to execute a line under current shell. Does that embedded linux's shell support >> operator? Have you tried it manually in the terminal?

Another thought is that your application may be run under some other user account and that account *could* have some weird configuration, like having some csh or ksh instead of bash (or viceversa, depending on what you like). Check what user actually owns the process and check the /etc/passwd for the shell setup.

Also, there is small possibility that the user account that the app runs under simply does not have rights to write to /tmp :) be sure to check that too

Also... there is small possibility that on yours 'embedded linux' simply has the system() implemented in a simplistic way, that just invokes the application with given parameters and skips all other shell-wise operators. This could have been done to save on resources, as system() might be though to be rarely used, or just though to be "too heavy" by your linux designers.. it depends on the distro.. If you tell us which one it is, then people with more knowledge will probably be able to say if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

On an embedded system, you are better off implementing the `system()` yourself. Consider the following code (**untested!**):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Helper function: Open the specified file at the desired descriptor.
*/
static int openfd(const int descriptor,
                  const char *const filename,
                  const int flags, const mode_t mode)
{
    int  fd, result;

    if (!filename || descriptor == -1)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    /* Close existing descriptor. Ignore errors. Hopefully it is reused. */
    do {
        result = close(descriptor);
    } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);

    /* Open the desired file. */
    do {
        fd = open(filename, flags, mode);
    } while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (fd == -1)
        return errno;

    /* Did we get lucky, and get the correct descriptor already? */
    if (fd == descriptor)
        return 0;

    /* Move the descriptor. */
    do {
        result = dup2(fd, descriptor);
    } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (result == -1) {
        const int  saved_errno = errno;
        do {
            result = close(fd);
        } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
        return errno = saved_errno;
    }

    /* Close the temporary descriptor. */
    do {
        result = close(fd);
    } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (result == -1) {
        const int  saved_errno = errno;
        do {
            result = close(descriptor);
        } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
        return errno = saved_errno;
    }

    return 0;
}

/* Start command on the background.
 * Note: args[1] is the first argument, args[0] is the command name.
 * NULL input/output/error redirects from/to /dev/null.
 * Empty string for input/output/error does no redirections;
 *   the command the uses the same input/output/error.
 * For non-empty output or error, specify the 'man 2 open' O_ flags too.
 *
 * Returns (pid_t)0 with errno set if an error occurs,
 * otherwise the PID of the child process started.
*/
pid_t run(const char *file,
          char *const args[],
          const char *const input,
          const char *const output, const int output_flags,
          const char *const error, const int error_flags)
{
    pid_t  child;
    int    result, flags;

    if (!cmd || !arg || !arg[0]) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return (pid_t)0;
    }

    child = fork();
    if (child == (pid_t)-1)
        return (pid_t)0;

    if (child)
        return child;

    /* This is the child process. */
    if (input && *input)
        result = openfd(STDIN_FILENO, input, O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY, 0);
    else
    if (!input)
        result = openfd(STDIN_FILENO, "/dev/null", O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY, 0);
    else
        result = 0;
    if (result)
        exit(127);

    if (output && *output)
        result = openfd(STDOUT_FILENO, output, output_flags, 0666);
    else
    if (!output)
        result = openfd(STDOUT_FILENO, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY | O_NOCTTY, 0);
    else
        result = 0;
    if (result)
        exit(127);

    if (error && *error)
        result = openfd(STDERR_FILENO, error, error_flags, 0666);
    else
    if (!error)
        result = openfd(STDERR_FILENO, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY | O_NOCTTY, 0);
    else
        result = 0;
    if (result)
        exit(127);

    execvp(file, args);

    exit(127);
}
```

The `run()` only starts the command, you'll need to wait for it to complete. Note that your main program can do meaningful work at the same time, unless it needs the exit status (or the files the command is supposed to create) right away. Example use:

```
/* Command to run. NULL terminates the list. */
char *const cmd[] = { "ls", "-l", NULL };

pid_t  child, p;
int    status;

child = run(cmd[0], cmd,
            NULL /* < /dev/null */,
            "/tmp/some-log-file", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND,
            "", 0 /* No redirection for standard error */);
if (!child) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot run '%s': %s.\n", cmd[0], strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}

do {
    status = 0;
    p = waitpid(child, &status, 0);
} while (p == (pid_t)-1 && errno == EINTR);
if (p == (pid_t)-1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Lost '%s': %s.\n", cmd[0], strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}

if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
    if (!WEXITSTATUS(status))
        printf("Command executed successfully.\n");
    else
        printf("Command failed with exit status %d.\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
} else
if (WSIGNALED(status))
    printf("Command died from signal %s.\n", strsignal(WTERMSIG(status)));
else
    printf("Command died unexpectedly.\n");
```

although the last part is often abbreviated to

```
if (WIFEXITED(status) && !WEXITSTATUS(status))
    printf("'%s': Successful.\n", cmd[0]);
else
    printf("'%s': Failed.\n", cmd[0]);
```

Note that if you process the output anyway, you probably should use a pipe (either `popen()` or an extended version of the above function) instead.

Hope you find this useful.